# graphql.parser.InvalidSyntaxException: Invalid Syntax : offending token '@' at line

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am not sure where it is occurring in my code base, since I am importing lot of common components. in general when we get these errors in graphql ?

Answer (score 1):

`graphql.parser.InvalidSyntaxException` generally happens when `graphql-java` trys to parse the schema definition or the graphql query but it founds there are syntax errors in them.

Parsing the schema definition usually happens during your application startup for configuring the `GraphQLSchema` object.

Parsing a graphql query happens during processing a graphql request